# sphinx, restructuredtext: set color for a single word

Tags: html, python-sphinx, restructuredtext

Is there a way to set the color of single words (or characters) in [sphinx](http://sphinx.pocoo.org/)? I'm pretty sure there should be some markup tag, like HTML's `font` tag.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you want to do this without being tied to html, try applying a different style than normal body text to your word.

In this example adapted from the rst2pdf manual, I apply the existing rubric style which is red in the backend that I am using:

```
Before red.

.. role:: rubric

I like color :rubric:`rubric`.

After red.
```

The actual look of the word will depend on how the style you choose is defined in the stylesheet that you use when generating your document.
If you want blue text, make a blue text style and derive it from the normal text style.
The stylsheet is backend-specific and you may be using the default.
To print the default for rst2pdf.py, do this (from the rst2pdf manual):

```
rst2pdf --print-stylesheet
```

Continuing the example for a rst2pdf stylesheet, add this to your stylesheet to have a blue text style:

```
bluetext:
  parent: bodytext
  textColor: blue
```

In the document you can reference this style to get a blue word.
Note this bit is generic, and should make blue text if you define a blue style in your html or whatever backend's stylesheet.

```
Before blue.

.. role:: bluetext

I like color :bluetext:`blue`.

After blue.
```

The generated pdf has the coloured words:
[image]

Comment: Actually RsT already supports color-roles by including the  `<s5defs.txt>` "standard" definition file (see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60991308/548792), below).

Answer (score 16):

On my Sphinx-powered [website](http://perso.crans.org/besson/), I use a combination of:

- A restructuredText file containing roles definitions, one for each color - see [.special.rst](http://bitbucket.org/lbesson/web-sphinx/raw/master/.special.rst) (BitBucket link)
- A CSS file containing color rules for each role - see the first lines of [hacks.css](http://bitbucket.org/lbesson/web-sphinx/raw/master/.static/hacks.css) (BitBucket link)

Then, in every rST file where I need colors, I first import `.special.rst` at the top, either manually:

```
.. include:: .special.rst
```

Or with the `rst_epilog` configuration variable in Sphinx's `conf.py` file:

```
rst_epilog = "\n.. include:: .special.rst\n"
```

And then each role can be used easily in pure rST syntax:

```
This is :red:`red !` And :blue:`this part is blue`.
```

More details are given on [this page](http://perso.crans.org/besson/avoir.html#une-experimentation-ajouter-facilement-des-couleurs-en-rst)  (in French, sorry).

It works perfectly well for html output (and html-like), but not for PDF. Refer to the [first answer above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9753677) for producing a PDF with colors.

Comment: I like this solution!

Comment: Thanks for this solution. It works but do you know how to solve `WARNING: Problems with "include" directive path:`? I don't know how to specify that `.special.rst` to be at project root directory in `conf.py`. I tried `/` and `~/` but neither works.

Comment: I don't know, in my case the `conf.py` file and all the `rst` files are in the same folder, so there is no need to specify anything.

Comment: After one year (see my first comment ;)) this solution is still great, although I have noticed (at least from my side), that after the first succesful build with `make html`, the following attempts to build with the same command always end up with (e.g. for red color)  `WARNING: Unknown interpreted text role "red".` warning. I have to do `make clean html` and then `make html` again. Other than this, everything works just fine.

Comment: Amazing solution. As @umbe1987 said, compile errors occur when rebuilding the HTML. I managed to fix it using `rst_prolog` instead of `rst_epilog`. The difference is that `rst_prolog` includes the file at the beginning, while `rst_epilog` includes it at the end ([See `rst_prolog` in Sphinx docs](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/configuration.html#confval-rst_prolog)).

Answer (score 15):

Sphinx **already supports colors** with the [`s5defs.txt`](https://docutils.sourceforge.io/docutils/parsers/rst/include/s5defs.txt) [*standard definition file*](https://docutils.sourceforge.io/docs/ref/rst/definitions.html) intended for [inclusion](https://docutils.sourceforge.io/docs/ref/rst/directives.html#including-an-external-document-fragment) (but is missing the CSS file):

1. Create/append this text to the value of [`rst_epilog`](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/configuration.html#confval-rst_prolog)
   sphinx configuration, in your `docs/conf.py` file:

   ```
    rst_prolog = """
    .. include:: <s5defs.txt>

    """
   ```
2. Follow [Sphinx's instructions](https://docs.readthedocs.io/en/stable/guides/adding-custom-css.html) to add a css with the colors
   (e.g. adopt the [`hack.css`](http://bitbucket.org/lbesson/web-sphinx/raw/master/.static/hacks.css) from [@Næreen's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35231016/548792)):

- Place your css file into e.g. `_static/css/s4defs-roles.css`;
- append it's path into [`shtml_css_files`](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/configuration.html#confval-html_css_files) sphinx configuration:

  ```
      html_css_files = ['css/s4defs-roles.css']
  ```

You may then use:

```
Some :red:`colored text` at last!
```

> **TIP:**
> Read [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32033158/create-a-role-font-color-in-sphinx-that-works-with-make-latexpdf) if you also want the styling to appear in *Latex* output.

Comment: An outright easy to follow solution for something which should not have been such a big deal in the first place. **Thank you.** One problem I faced though - i.e. with the `.. default-role::` in `rst-prolog` in `conf.py` file, my page layout was going haywire. Initially I made major changes in the `.css` file. But in the end I realized that `.. default-role::` was the real culprit. Removing it made everything fall in place. **Including the font color!!**

Comment: Thank @shaan!  Fixed.

Answer (score 7):

This works, but leaves the HTML in a separate paragraph.

```
.. raw:: html

    <font color="blue">Blue word,</font>

And a word without color
```

If anyone has a better answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 4):

Just a quick note because I landed here looking for something similar for `html`.

This works on Sphinx v2.0.1 for me. This uses the concept reported by @adam-matan but doesn't cause any formatting issues (i.e. the paragraph problem).

reference: [reStructuredText Directives](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/ref/rst/directives.html#raw-data-pass-through)

```
.. role:: raw-html(raw)
   :format: html

:raw-html:`<font color="blue">Blue word,</font>` And a word without color
```