# How to use color in text with ReStructured Text (rst2html.py) or how to insert HTML tags without blank lines?

Tags: html, restructuredtext, rst2html.py

How can I use color with ReStructured Text? For example, `**hello**` translates into `<strong>hello</strong>`. How can I make ReStructure(rst2html.py) translate **something**  into `<font color="####">text</font>`?

I thought about ..raw:: html, but it introduces blank lines. I want to insert HTML tags without blank lines.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

I found this method working

First, you have the role.

```
.. role:: red

An example of using :red:`interpreted text`
```

It translates into as follows.

```
<p>An example of using <span class="red">interpreted text</span></p>
```

Now, you have the red class, you can use CSS for changing colors.

```
.red {
    color:red;
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to define the role globally once in conf.py instead of defining it in all the rst files where it's used?

Comment: @locke14 use the ["standard" RsT colors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3702865/sphinx-restructuredtext-set-color-for-a-single-word/60991308#60991308) and then add either the CSS file to your [a `docutils.conf` file](https://docutils.sourceforge.io/docs/user/config.html#configuration-files) or use the `--stylesheetXXX` options of `rst2html.py` command.  With Sphinx it's possible to avoid the `.. include::` directive on every page by using the [`rst_epilogue` config-value](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/configuration.html#confval-rst_epilog) to import content for all pages

Answer (score 29):

Well, I am a new user now, therefore I can not comment on others answer, thanks to stackoverflow's policy here. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51926/new-users-cant-ask-for-clarifications-except-as-answers

Sienkiew's answer is good, but I want to make correction about its last sentence.

There IS way to specify the style sheet in the RST file. The clue is in Prosseek's original post, that is the .. raw:: directive.

We can put following lines at the beginning of our RST file to specify its style.

```
.. raw:: html

    <style> .red {color:red} </style>
```

Comment: I [tried](https://github.com/jalanb/pym/commit/c10254f2035e10f7d4bbeb711b69880e32c8df86) this, but [ReadTheDocs](https://pym.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) gnerated `<span class="problematic" id="id4">:red:`red`</span>`

Answer (score 10):

The other answer here hints at what I wanted to do, but it assumes some detailed knowledge about stylesheets in docutils.  Here is a a cookbook explanation:

In your RST file, declare the role once, then use it:

```
    .. role:: red

    This text is :red:`colored red` and so is :red:`this`
```

Then you need a style sheet file.  First, use Python to copy the default style sheet out of the docutils package:

```
    python
    import os.path
    import shutil
    import docutils.writers.html4css1 as h
    shutil.copy(os.path.dirname(h.__file__)+"/html4css1.css","my.css")
```

Then edit my.css to add your customizations at the end:

```
    .red {
            color: red;
    }
```

Create a docutils configuration file named "docutils.conf":

```
    [html4css1 writer]
    stylesheet-path: my.css
    embed-stylesheet: yes
```

use rst2html.py to convert your document:

```
    rst2html.py my_document.rst > my_document.html
```

If you don't want to use docutils.conf, you can specify the style sheet every time you run rst2html:

```
    rst2html.py --stylesheet my.css my_document.rst > my_document.html
```

AFAIK, there is no way to specify the style sheet in the RST file.

Comment: That seems like a good (and well-written solution). Plus, you wouldn't really want to add a style sheet in the rst file, because the goal would be to use one file for multiple formats. So if you later decide, "heck, I want to change how I define red", you can do that more easily.

Answer (score 4):

Works for me like this:

```
.. raw:: html

    <style> .red {color:#aa0060; font-weight:bold; font-size:16px} </style>

.. role:: red

:red:`test - this text should be red``
```

Answer (score 3):

Sphinx **already supports colors** with the [`s5defs.txt`](https://docutils.sourceforge.io/docutils/parsers/rst/include/s5defs.txt) [*standard definition file*](https://docutils.sourceforge.io/docs/ref/rst/definitions.html) intended for [inclusion](https://docutils.sourceforge.io/docs/ref/rst/directives.html#including-an-external-document-fragment) (but is missing the CSS file):

1. Create/append this text to the value of [`rst_epilog`](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/configuration.html#confval-rst_epilog)
   sphinx configuration, in your `docs/conf.py` file:

   ```
   rst_prolog = """
   .. include:: <s5defs.txt>
   .. default-role::

   """
   ```
2. Follow [Sphinx's instructions](https://docs.readthedocs.io/en/stable/guides/adding-custom-css.html) to add a css with the colors 
   (e.g. adopt the [`hack.css`](http://bitbucket.org/lbesson/web-sphinx/raw/master/.static/hacks.css) from [@Næreen's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35231016/548792)):

   - Place your css file into e.g. `_static/css/s4defs-roles.css`;
   - append it's path into [`shtml_css_files`](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/configuration.html#confval-html_css_files) sphinx configuration:

     ```
     html_css_files = [
         'css/s4defs-roles.css',
     ]
     ```

You may then use:

```
Some :red:`colored text` at last!
```

> **TIP:**
>    Read [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32033158/create-a-role-font-color-in-sphinx-that-works-with-make-latexpdf) if you also want the styling to appear in *Latex* output.

Answer (score 1):

Combining @prosseek's and @RayLuo's answers all in one place - to make easier to find

At the top of your RST file, place

```
.. raw:: html

    <style> .red {color:red} </style>

.. role:: red

:red:`test - this text should be red`
```

SIDE COMMENT:

Of course, many folks will want the style in a separate file, as @sienkiew says.

But not always.

E.g. I am generating the above from a script that I want other users to be able to run, often from a file URL.  Depending on rst2html.py is bad enough - requiring something nonstandard to be in a config file is worse.

If there were a way to create a weak local definition for the style - e.g. "if there is no style .red already defined use this, but otherwise use the style already defined" - would be nice.  But AFAIK local definitions are stronger.

This ran with `rst2html.py (Docutils 0.13.1 [release], Python 3.6.4, on cygwin)`, but other RST tools rejected.

Answer (score 0):

RST file can be render by [docutils](https://docutils.sourceforge.io/) or [Sphinx](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/)(In fact, Sphinx use docutils too.)

## Sphinx

If you need complete documentation, then choose Sphinx.
You only need to set your styles once, and then you can use it for all places.
that is concerned about `config.py`, `your_css`, `your_role`

## docutils

If you just want to generate a simple HTML file, I think it is more convenient to embed CSS in RST below is an example,

### MyRST2html.py

It's pretty similar to the `rst2html.py`,
I just want to write the script by myself, and it's convenient to hack the source (and learning more from it.), and then you can customize it to your cool style

```py
# MyRST2html.py
import docutils.core
from pathlib import Path

source_path = Path('demo.rst')
destination_path = Path('output.html')

if not 'save all data':
    docutils.core.publish_file(source_path=source_path, destination=destination_path, writer_name='html')
elif 'save the body data only':
    with open(source_path, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        html_bytes: bytes = docutils.core.publish_string(f.read(), source_path, writer_name='html')
    html = html_bytes.decode('utf-8')
    html_data = html[html.find('<body>'):html.find('</body>')]
    with open(destination_path, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        f.write(html_data)
        f.write('</body>')
```

### demo.rst

```
.. raw:: html

    <style>
        .red {color:red; font-weight:bold;}
        .b {color:#0000FF; background-color:white;}
    </style>

.. role:: red
.. role:: b

==========
Example
==========

.. contents::

Color
==========

:red:`R`\G\ :b:`B`

click me |RGB Colors|_

.. |RGB Colors| replace:: :red:`R`\G\ :b:`B`
.. _`RGB Colors`: https://www.w3schools.com/colors/colors_rgb.asp
```

### output.html

```html
<body>
<div class="document" id="example">
<h1 class="title">Example</h1>

<style>
    .red {color:red; font-weight:bold;}
    .b {color:#0000FF; background-color:white;}
</style><div class="contents topic" id="contents">
<p class="topic-title">Contents</p>
<ul class="simple">
<li><a class="reference internal" href="#color" id="id1">Color</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="section" id="color">
<h1><a class="toc-backref" href="#id1">Color</a></h1>
<p><span class="red">R</span>G<span class="b">B</span></p>
<p>click me <a class="reference external" href="https://www.w3schools.com/colors/colors_rgb.asp"><span class="red">R</span>G<span class="b">B</span></a></p>
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

### note

If your IDE is [PyCharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/), it's Ok to see the result on the [Editor and Preview](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/restructured-text.html#create-rst)

[image]