# Applying CSS and roles for text blocks instead of inline spans in Sphinx

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext

There is [a previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4669689/) that explains how to add a color span to some reStructuredText.

To recap the procedure:

First, you have the role.

```
.. role:: red

An example of using :red:`interpreted text`
```

It translates into as follows.

```
<p>An example of using <span class="red">interpreted text</span></p>
```

Now, you have the red class, you can use CSS for changing colors.

```
.red {
    color:red;
}
```

How do you do this if you want text that spans multiple lines?  For example:

```
.. role:: red

:red:`paragraph 1

      paragraph 2

      paragraph 3`
```

Where paragraph 1, 2, & 3 would all be "red".  If I try to do this I get the warning message:

> WARNING: Inline interpreted text or phrase reference start-string without end-string.

It doesn't create the span and inserts ":red:" into the text.  It just doesn't interpret this as a string (as the warning suggests).

Basically, can this be done in reStructuredText, and if it can, how?

I'm using Sphinx 1.1.3.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There are a number of ways to do this, but one of them is to use the `class` directive:

```
.. class:: red

    This is a paragraph.

    This is another paragraph.
```

Most docutils HTML writers will put that into html output as a class html attribute, which you can then style with CSS.

In Sphinx, in particular, however, you may need to use `rst-class` instead of `class` in at least some cases.  See: https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/2.0/usage/restructuredtext/basics.html

Also, many block-level elements in RestructuredText take a `:class:` parameter which does pretty much the same thing.

Comment: can you do this on an image substitution e.g. `.. |myicon| image:: /path/to/image.png` ? I want to apply a class anytime I use `|myicon|`