# Resume list numbering after class

Tags: html-lists, restructuredtext

I have a restructured text enumerated list, which I export to HTML with `rst2html`:

```
#. My first point
#. My second, very important point
#. My third, very important point
#. My fourth point
```

I would like to highlight the second and third point, which are clearly very important. This is easily done with:

```
#. My first point

.. class:: red

   #. My second, very important point
   #. My third, very important point
#. My fourth point
```

However, this restarts the numbering (i.e. the second and forth point will be 1), while I want to continue on. Is it possible?

I have considered the inline role `` :red:`important point `` syntax, but it doesn't fit my scenario (it's a very long list of red points, and I don't want to add the inline role to each line).

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
#. My first point

   .. class:: red
#. My second, very important point

#. My third, very important point

#. My fourth point
```

You can't set a class for the first item that way, though.

Answer (score -1):

What about adding a class to each of the important list items?

```
<li class="important">Important</li>
```

and then styling it appropriately?

You can also use the nth-child selector, if you know which item should be highlighted

```
li:nth-child(2) {
    color: red;
}
```

Comment: Sure, but how do I add a class to the `li` from the reST?

Comment: I can't think of other approach than adding the role for each of your important li elements. Like in this case: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4669689/how-to-use-color-in-text-with-restructured-text-rst2html-py-or-how-to-insert-h/4669850#4669850

Comment: Yes, precisely. That's what I do at the moment (see last line of my question). I don't think there is a proper solution then.