# How do I highlight text in python-sphinx?

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext

I'm looking for a way to highlight text in python sphinx.
I have seen documentation on how to change the font colour of individual words, but I want to change the background colour of individual words.

Comment: What documentation? If you know how to change the font colour, it seems like it  would be straigthforward to adapt that solution to also change the background colour.

Comment: This https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3702865/sphinx-restructuredtext-set-color-for-a-single-word
If you know of a way to highlight a word with a chosen colour, please let me know. I don't see how to use font styles for this.

Comment: That question has three upvoted answers. What exactly did you try?

Comment: I have tried all three solutions. None of them do what I want to accomplish. These solutions change the colour of the font itself. I want to highlight words by changing the background colour of a single word, the same way you would highlight a word on paper with a fluorescent marker.

Comment: Please elaborate the question. Make it clear what output format this is about. **Show us** what you have tried. Provide examples. Don't just say "None of them do what I want".

Comment: I may be wrong, but as far as I can tell, any formatting options applied to a txt or rst file should be reflected in any output format, be it HTML, PDF or ePUB. 
I cannot show what for obvious reasons doesn't work. Since font colour is the opposite of what I am trying to accomplish I have not provided any example other than the examples provided in the documentation I have provided a link to above. Those font colour solutions work, but are the opposite of what I wish to accomplish.

Answer (score 1):

Sphinx **already supports highlighted text** with the [`s5defs.txt`](https://docutils.sourceforge.io/docutils/parsers/rst/include/s5defs.txt) [*standard definition file*](https://docutils.sourceforge.io/docs/ref/rst/definitions.html) intended for [inclusion](https://docutils.sourceforge.io/docs/ref/rst/directives.html#including-an-external-document-fragment) (but is missing the CSS file):

1. Create/append this text to the value of [`rst_epilog`](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/configuration.html#confval-rst_epilog)
   sphinx configuration, in your `docs/conf.py` file:

   ```py
   rst_epilog = """
   .. include:: <s5defs.txt>
   """
   ```
2. Follow [Sphinx's instructions](https://docs.readthedocs.io/en/stable/guides/adding-custom-css.html) to add a CSS with the *outline* you like:

   - Place your css file into e.g. `_static/css/s4defs-roles.css`;
   - append it's path into [`shtml_css_files`](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/configuration.html#confval-html_css_files) sphinx configuration:

     ```py
     html_css_files = [
         'css/s4defs-roles.css',
     ]
     ```

You may then use:

```
Some :outline:`outlined text` at last!
```

> **TIP:**
>    Read [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32033158/create-a-role-font-color-in-sphinx-that-works-with-make-latexpdf) if you also want the styling to appear in *Latex* output.